# Take bookings from guest user and verify email

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication

We have a requirement in our ASP dot net core application, where we need to take booking from a guest user. But first we need to make OTP verification for the user's email and mobile.

The user needs to access our system only until the booking is complete and hence we do not want to add this user as a permanent identity user.

I found articles suggesting to create our own OTP logic.

Is there any better way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need your own OTP logic, which is similar to **Two-Factor Authentication** or **Two-Step Verification**. Either way, this should be easy to implement.

Most importantly, it depends on your verification method and platform.

For example, if you want to send a code to a phone number, then you can choose [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/en-us) to do it. Regarding some of its configurations, you can configure them according to [Microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1). And here is a complete example you can refer to: [Two-Factor(2FA) Authentication using IdentityServer4, Twilio and .NET 5](https://github.com/csehammad/2FAUsingIdentityServer4).

Or you just want to verify by Identity sending verification code to email: [Two-Step Verification with ASP.NET Core Identity](https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/identity-aspnetcore/tree/two-step-verification-identity).

Of course there is another way, use the [OTP.NET library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Otp.NET/) to generate and verify the OTP token, then temporarily store the key with the user session, and then send it to the user for verification, as described in [this article](https://enlear.academy/otp-login-with-net-core-for-mobile-friendly-web-apps-36b721592821).

Of course, how you do the validation is ultimately up to you, these are just some of the common ones.